# Open links in dedicated app, rather than a web browser

Tags: functionality, microsoft-edge

Is there any way to force Windows to open URL links with a dedicated app?

For example, somebody texted me a link to their LinkedIn profile. Clicking the click loads the page in the Edge browser. However, I would like it to open with the LinkedIn app I have installed.

I am using Windows Phone 10, but as I recall this was a problem for me in 8 and 8.1 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps can be launched from the browser via uri protocol activation.

For example, if you were to visit `bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076` in Edge on the phone (or Internet Explorer 11 on Windows Phone 8.1), it would instead redirect and open the maps app.

For this to work for LinkedIn; they would need to have implemented [protocol activation](http://devhammer.net/blog/protocol-activation-what-is-it-what-apps-offer-it-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-my-apps/), and have their website redirect to it when you visit their website.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way the user can force the OS to open certain links in certain apps. There are some apps that can open their links in other apps (e.g. Aeries can open YouTube apps in MyTube), but this is up to the developer to implement.